# how can I type check this particular function?

Tags: javascript

It turns out prompt always returns a string, how can I type check this. I'm attempting to check a name to see if it contains numbers.

```
function getName(){
        try{
            let name=prompt("please type a name").toLowerCase();

            for(let i=0; i<name.length; i++){

                if( typeof name[i] != "string"){
                    throw Error("invalid response");
                }
            }
            return name;
        }
        catch(err){
                console.log(err);
                console.log("please try again");
                getName();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should give us more examples of valid and invalid prompt inputs. Because the string `fdsfdsf123dsfsd` also contains numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to do is test that there are *any* numbers in the string, then you can just use a simple Regex to test that:

```
var regex = /\d+/g;
regex.test(name); // returns true if there are any numbers anywhere in the string
```

If you want to see if there are only letters, you can do it this way instead:

```
var regex = /[a-zA-Z]+/g;
regex.test(name); // returns true only if all characters are letters
```

Comment: `a-d` rather than `a-z`?

Comment: @Andy this is what I get for getting onto  Stack before my first coffee. Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

This function identifies integer even amongst strings

```
function hasNumbers(t) {
   return /\d/.test(t);
}

hasNumbers ("name") //false
hasNumbers ("name123") //true
hasNumbers ("na124me") //true
```